# Converting date in MS Access to SQL Server date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I've copied, pasted, and converted a query from Access into SQL Server but can't seem to figure out how to convert the Access dates into SQL Server friendly formats.

The person who wrote the application is gone so I'm on my own. Here are a couple of examples:

```
 SetupDate Between '120701' And '151299'
 SetupDate Between '001000' And '151299'
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with access, but how are these dates?  Is this `DDMMYY`?

Comment: "from Access into SQL" - what does that mean? SQL exists in Access as well. Are you running a query in Access with tables linked from SQL Server, a pass-through query in Access, or is it a (one-off) query in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that format with sql server, you need your dates in yyyymmdd format.  So this:

```
SetupDate Between '120701' And '151299'
```

becomes this:

```
SetupDate Between '20120701' And '20151299'
```

except that '20151299' is not a valid date.  So maybe it should be this:

```
    SetupDate Between '20010701' And '19991215'
```

in which case you probably won't get any records.

Answer (score 0):

if my guess is correct, `SetupDate` contain 6 digit dates, then if possible, create a temporary column `SetupDate2 AS DATE` 
then update :

```
update myTable
set SetupDate2 = CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(SetupDate, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SetupDate, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SetupDate, 5, 2))
```

then drop `SetupDate` and rename `SetupDate2` to `SetupDate`

below is a test on your sample:

```
SetupDate BETWEEN
        CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING('120701', 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('120701', 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('120701', 5, 2))
        AND CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING('151299', 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('151299', 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('151299', 5, 2))
SetupDate BETWEEN
        CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING('001000', 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('001000', 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('001000', 5, 2))
        AND CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING('151299', 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('151299', 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('151299', 5, 2))
```

Comment: I should have specified.  Here is the format:  2010-06-11

Comment: the format of what ? is `SetupDate` an NVARCHAR(10) ? or it is DATE ?

Comment: perfect ! if you follow my instructions, you'll get the desired result.